# WebLogic 12.1.1.0 is truncating dynamically generated XML file

Tags: vmware-fusion, xml

this is my first question on SU/StackOverflow, so bear with me...

We've got an exploded application, residing on a NAS mount, that we just moved from WebLogic 6.1 to WLS 12.1.1.0. Believe it or not, everything code-wise works just fine without any kind of rewrite.

HOWEVER, we've got this *single* XML file that is generated daily with a new line (for the new date) that just won't render properly. It appears to be truncating:

```
 <z:row Sch10Date='09/16/2012' BillingDayDesignation='B' CountsAsDayDesignation='B' WEBComment='                 '/>
            <z:row Sch10Date='09/17/2012' BillingDayDesignation='B' CountsAsDayDesignation='B' WEBComment='                 '/>

            <z:row Sch10Date='09/18/2012' BillingDayDesignation='B' CountsAsDayDesignation='B' WEBComment='                 '/>
            <z:row Sch10Date='09/19/2012' BillingDayDesignation='B' CountsAsDayDesignation='B' WEBComment='                 '/>
            <z:row Sch10Date='09/20/2012' BillingDayDesignation='B' CountsAsDayDesignation='B' WEBComment='                 '/>
            <z:row Sch10Date='09/21/2012' BillingDayDesignation='B' CountsAsDayDesignation='B' WEBComment='                 '/>
            <z:row Sch10Date='0
```

All other XML files (the rest are static) render just fine. If I stop the WebLogic instance, and clear the cache, the dynamic XML renders just fine. However, as soon as the daily recreating of that file happens, once again we get a truncated XML file.

This would lead me to believe the WLS is doing some squirrely caching thing, but I'm not real sure where to look from here. Haven't found anything online, and I've contacted support at a certain software company that kindda sounds like "abhorable" or "deplorable", but working with them makes me want to jump out of a window... And the likelihood of a prompt resolution is equal to the likelihood of me surviving that fall.

...so I figured I'd turn to you wonderful, brilliant, good-looking people.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'll be honest, I left that job about 10 months ago, and don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did managed to find a solution using this parameter into the weblogic.xml file:

```
<container-descriptor>

   <resource-reload-check-secs>0</resource-reload-check-secs>

</container-descriptor>
```

Basically forcing the application to reload every time a new XML/CSS/JS file is loaded.